# How to select an option from notification prompt in browsers using robot framework

Tags: browser, safari, notifications, popup, robotframework

Is there a way to choose an option from popup notifications (E.g. for location, password, translation etc.) that appear in the browsers by using robot framework?

Image 1:

[image]

Image 2:

[image]

Image 3:

[image]

Image 4:

[image]

Comment: You are starting browser with keyword open browser only?

Comment: Can you add the images inline, this is not easy to view otherwise.

Comment: @A.Kootstra Sorry, I am not able to add images inline since there is a notification that I need at least 10 reputation to post images.

Comment: @YashJagdale Yes, I am using the keyword "Open browser" and for e.g. in firefox a popup to don't allow/allow access my location appears. In some cases I need to select "don't allow", in others cases I need to allow it.

Answer (score 1):

**1. For Location pop up** :- 
for such cases you need to enable or disable location access through desire capabilities of browser. for example in case of location access you need to set **"disable-geolocation"** in your chrome options, similarly you need to set

```
FirefoxProfile geoDisabled = new FirefoxProfile();
geoDisabled.setPreference("geo.enabled", false);
geoDisabled.setPreference("geo.provider.use_corelocation", false);
geoDisabled.setPreference("geo.prompt.testing", false);
geoDisabled.setPreference("geo.prompt.testing.allow", false
```

**2. For Password save popup:-**
For this you need to set Experimental option in chrome by setting **"credentials_enable_service"** and **"profile.password_manager_enabled"** as false.

Example:-

```
${list} =     Create List    --disable-geolocation      --start-maximized      --profile.password_manager_enabled=false       --credentials_enable_service=false
${args} =     Create Dictionary    args=${list}
${desired caps} =     Create Dictionary    platform=${OS}     chromeOptions=${args}
Open Browser    https://www.google.com    remote_url=${grid_url}    browser=${BROWSER}    desired_capabilities=${desired caps}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try selenium library-Handle alert Keyword. It will be helpful in handling all pop up related tasks.

http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Handle%20Alert

ACCEPT: Accept the alert i.e. press Ok. Default.
DISMISS: Dismiss the alert i.e. press Cancel.
LEAVE: Leave the alert open.

Eg:

Handle Alert     action=ACCEPT

Comment: Please provide a comment when asking if a certain approach has been tried or provide a working code example or description for something you know works. This suggestion also won't work as these are not HTML alerts, but browser level alerts and they are not accessible in Selenium.

Comment: looks like you are thinking of application pop/alerts. But que is more on browser level pop(normally called native  popups) doesn't get handled through selenium(using driver object), You have DC(desire capability for the same)